# Can't save content or make changes - Liferay

Tags: liferay

Liferay 6.1.1 CE GA2 works works fine-and-dandy on my local machine and my coworkers as well. When we deploy it to our main dev server, we find that we can't save any changes (i.e., create web content, change theme/schemes, etc).

Any idea why this is happening?

Cheers!

Comment: your question is very abstract. can you give proper details ? log details etc

Answer (score 1):

- check the log output, this might give you hints on what's going wrong
- If you get UI errors, this might help as well
- check what database you're connecting with, make sure that the user account you use has write access to the database
- In case you use hsql (don't do this unless on an unimportant demo server) make sure that the user your appserver runs as is able to write to the data directory and persist the database
- If you're running on a cluster and the second machine doesn't pick up changes made through the first machine, you need to configure clustering properly. The Userguide at https://www.liferay.com/documentation/ has a chapter on this.

If nothing of this helps, please give more information